# Filter Array of Dictionary Objects by key and last value of that specified key

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, filter

Assuming the following data:

```
var randomData = [[0: 0.0], [0: 0.005399568], [0: 0.031317495], [0: 0.059395213], [0: 0.08531314], [0: 0.111231074], [0: 0.13066952], [0: 0.15010796], [0: 0.16954641], [0: 0.18898486], [0: 0.21058308], [0: 0.23002152], [0: 0.25593945], [0: 0.2753779], [0: 0.28833687], [0: 0.29697624], [0: 0.30129582], [0: 0.3056155], [0: 0.3056155], [0: 0.30777532], [0: 0.30777532], [0: 0.30993518], [0: 0.3142548], [0: 0.3142548], [0: 0.3142548], [0: 0.3142548], [0: 0.3142548], [0: 0.3142548], [0: 0.3142548], [2: 0.0010798806], [2: 0.072354175], [2: 0.072354175], [2: 0.12203024], [2: 0.1717062], [2: 0.21922246], [2: 0.26889843], [2: 0.30993518], [2: 0.3423326], [2: 0.36393085], [2: 0.3790496], [2: 0.39200857], [2: 0.40280774], [2: 0.41144702], [2: 0.42224622], [2: 0.4265659], [2: 0.4330454], [2: 0.43736497], [2: 0.44168466], [2: 0.44384444], [2: 0.44600433], [2: 0.4524838], [2: 0.46544278], [2: 0.47840175], [2: 0.4892008], [2: 0.4978402], [2: 0.50431967], [2: 0.50647944], [2: 0.50647944], [2: 0.50647944], [2: 0.50647944], [2: 0.50647944], [2: 0.51079917], [2: 0.5172786], [2: 0.5215982], [2: 0.5237581], [2: 0.5237581], [2: 0.5237581], [2: 0.5237581], [2: 0.5237581], [4: 0.0], [4: 0.07451397], [4: 0.07451397], [4: 0.10691138], [4: 0.1393088], [4: 0.1738661], [4: 0.20842329], [4: 0.24298048], [4: 0.28401726], [4: 0.32073426], [4: 0.35529158], [4: 0.3790496], [4: 0.39848804], [4: 0.41144702], [4: 0.42224622], [4: 0.4287257], [4: 0.4330454], [4: 0.43736497], [4: 0.44600433], [4: 0.4524838], [4: 0.46760258], [4: 0.48056152], [4: 0.4978402], [4: 0.51295894], [4: 0.5237581], [4: 0.5280777], [4: 0.53455716], [4: 0.54319656], [4: 0.54967606], [4: 0.5539956], [4: 0.55831534], [4: 0.562635], [4: 0.57343405], [4: 0.57991356], [4: 0.58639306], [4: 0.5907127], [4: 0.5907127], [4: 0.5907127], [4: 0.5928725], [4: 0.5928725], [4: 0.5928725], [5: 0.003239675], [5: 0.09179262], [5: 0.09179262], [5: 0.1393088], [5: 0.1738661], [5: 0.19330454], [5: 0.20842329], [5: 0.21706256], [5: 0.22570194], [5: 0.2343412], [5: 0.24298048], [5: 0.25161988], [5: 0.26241893], [5: 0.2775378], [5: 0.29265654], [5: 0.3034557], [5: 0.3142548], [5: 0.31857446], [5: 0.32073426], [5: 0.32073426], [5: 0.32073426], [5: 0.32073426], [5: 0.32073426], [5: 0.32073426]]
```

How would I go about filtering randomData into an variable [[Int: Float]] that returns the last object for each key. In other words the expected result would be:

```
[[0: 0.3142548], [2: 0.5237581], [4: 0.5928725], [5: 0.32073426]]
```

I thought the logic would be to create arrays for each key then take the last element, and repurpose that into an array but that's only pulling the last element and not the last element **for each key**

```
let filtered = randomData.filter({$0.keys == $0.keys}).last
// Optional([5: 0.32073426])

let filtered = randomData.map({$0.filter({$0.key == $0.key})}).last
//Optional([5: 0.32073426])
```

Any advice and direction is appreciate as always.

Comment: 1-element dictionaries are not a Swifty solution. Try [KeyValuePairs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyvaluepairs) and do what Alexander said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by grouping the elements based on the inner dictionary key and then selecting the last element of each group

```
let selected = Dictionary(grouping: randomData, by: { $0.keys.first })
    .compactMap { $0.value.last }
```

As suggested by @Alexander in the comments this can be solved more directly using `Dictionary(_:uniqueKeysWith:)`

```
let selected = Dictionary(randomData.flatMap { $0 }, uniquingKeysWith: {
    return $0 > $1 ?  $0 : $1
})
```

The two solutions yield a slightly different result, the first an array of dictionaries and the second one a dictionary as can be seen below

> First solution: [[2: 0.5237581], [4: 0.5928725], [5: 0.32073426], [0: 0.3142548]]
> Second solution: [0: 0.3142548, 5: 0.32073426, 4: 0.5928725, 2: 0.5237581]

Comment: You can also use [`Dictionary.init(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127161-init). Every time there's a collision, you take the latest of the two values. At the end, you'll end up with a dict mapping keys to the last values, and you'll avoid the intermediate dictionary-of-arrays

Comment: @Alexander Thanks. It's always good to break old habits (solutions) which `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` certainly is for me.